# Wordpress, Order by mutliples values for same meta key

Tags: wordpress

I want to order or group all the posts with meta_value with same meta_key. 
 All posts with meta_value 'CCC' and with 'AAA' and with 'BBB',...

I try with this :

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'=>'a_post_meta_key',
        'value'=> array('CCC','AAA','BBB','DDD')
    )
),
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'DESC',
```

And this :

```
'meta_query'     => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'ccc_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'a_post_meta_key',
        'value' => 'CCC',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    'aaa_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'a_post_meta_key',
        'value' => 'AAA',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    'bbb_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'a_post_meta_key',
        'value' => 'BBB',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
),
'orderby' => array(
    'ccc_clause' => 'DESC',
    'aaa_clause' => 'DESC',
    'bbb_clause' => 'DESC',
),
```

But no good results. Do you have any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: do you already run the query using Wp_query()? if yes what is the result?

Comment: Hello @dennisgon, the orderby is made by the default wp_query orderby...

Comment: What method 1 or 2 is good for you ?